# TextInputDialog's Graphic won't resize

Tags: javafx, dialog

I created a `TextInputDialog` in JavaFX using *this* constructor :

```
public class CostumTextInputDialog extends TextInputDialog {

        public CostumTextInputDialog(String headerText, String contentText, String iconURL) throws FileNotFoundException {
            setHeaderText(headerText);
            setContentText(contentText);
            getDialogPane().setMinSize(400,260);
            setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream(iconURL))));
            getGraphic().maxWidth(20);
            getGraphic().maxHeight(20);
            showAndWait();
        }
    }
```

I called constructor here and passed the icon's URL in the parameters as defined in the constructor, but the icon is waay too big and i tried resizing it but it's not working for some reason,here's the code:

```
CostumTextInputDialog coverDialog = new CostumTextInputDialog(
            "Creating a new table",
            "Enter cover count :",
            "src\\ICONS\\team.png");
```

what am i missing here ?

**This is how is looks with MaxWidth and MaxHeight set to `20px`**

[image: Dialog]

Comment: Please try e. g. `imageView.setFitHeight(20);` and have a look here: [ImageView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html)

Comment: it worked ! Thank you , but i still dont understand why getGraphic().maxWidth(20)  didnt ?

Comment: @Coffeeguru Read the documentation for that method. It doesn’t do what you are assuming it does.